# How to color only the coefficients of a system of equations?

Tags: equations, color, align, systeme

How to color only the coefficients of an aligned system of equation? I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

And so far, I've tried using these packages and defining these colors:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{V}{HTML}{00a2e8}
\definecolor{R}{HTML}{fbc200}
\definecolor{B}{HTML}{000000}
```

The problem I have is that apparently the systeme environment won't allow me to color the minus sign of the coefficients (I guess is using them to identify every term in the equations) nor the equal symbol. So this is what I've tried:

```
\begin{equation*}\mathcolor{R}{
  \systeme[I_{1}I_{2}I_{3}I_{4}]{
    6\color{B}{I_{1}}-3\color{B}{I_{2}} -1\color{B}{I_{3}}=\color{V}{5},
    -3\color{B}{I_{1}} +7\color{B}{I_{2}} -2\color{B}{I_{4}}=\color{V}{-23},
    -1\color{B}{I_{1}}+3\color{B}{I_{3}} -1\color{B}{I_{4}}=\color{V}{5},
    -2\color{B}{I_{2}} -1\color{B}{I_{3}} +4\color{B}{I_{4}}=\color{V}{3}
  }}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Here, the problem with this approach is that the delimiter and the equal symbol are yellow and when I try to color them black, I get an error message that reads: "! L'indice n'est pas un nombre entier !."]

On the other hand, when I try this:

```
    \begin{equation}
\systeme*{
    \color{R}{6}\color{B}{I_{1}} -\color{R}{3}\color{B}{I_{2}}-\color{R}{1}\color{B}{I_{3}}=\color{V}{5},
    \color{R}-3\color{B}{I_{1}}+\color{R}{7}\color{B}{I_{2}} -\color{R}{2}\color{B}{I_{4}}=\color{V}{-23},
    \color{R}{-1}\color{B}{I_{1}}+\color{R}{3}\color{B}{I_{3}}-\color{R}{1}\color{B}{I_{4}}=\color{V}{5},
    \color{R}-\color{R}{2}\color{B}{I_{2}}-\color{R}{1}\color{B}{I_{3}} +\color{R}{4}\color{B}{I_{4}}=\color{V}{3}
}
\end{equation}
```

I get this output:

[image: And the problem here is that I don't get the minus signs colored, apparently for the same reason I cannot color the equal symbols in the previous approach.]

I know technically, the minus signs, as I wrote the equations, are not part of the coefficients, but rather a shortened way of saying + (-k) where k is a real number. But, I thought that there might be a way to get the LaTeX formatted version of the first image I uploaded. Hence, if you have any idea of what that way is, I'll be very grateful to you :)

PS:Just in case somebody is wondering, that's the system I get from an electric circuit, so that's where the name of the variables come from.

Answer (score 6):

Here, I build it from scratch as a TABstack.  I use `tokcycle` only insofar as employing it's token-list building macro `\addcytoks` to build the `\cytoks` token register.

I use `listofitems` to parse the coefficients and to build up the token register, which in the end gets passed to the TABstack.

Syntax is

```
\mysystem{<color1>}{<color2>}{<Variable>}{<coefficients>}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,tokcycle,xcolor,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\newcommand\mysystem[4]{%
 \begingroup
 \setsepchar{\\/&}%
 \readlist\zlist{#4}%
 \foreachitem\z\in\zlist[]{%
   \foreachitem\zz\in\zlist[\zcnt]{%
     \if\relax\zz\relax\addcytoks{&}\ifnum\zzcnt=1\relax\else
       \addcytoks{&&}\fi\else
     \ifnum\zzcnt=\listlen\zlist[1]\addcytoks{&{}={}&}\relax\else
       \ifnum\zzcnt=1\else\ifnum\zz<0\addcytoks{&&}\else
         \addcytoks{&{}+{}&}\fi\fi\fi
     \ifnum\zzcnt=\listlen\zlist[1]\relax\addcytoks{\textcolor{#2}\bgroup}%
       \else\addcytoks{\textcolor{#1}\bgroup}\fi
     \addcytoks[1]{\expandafter{\zz}\egroup}%
     \ifnum\zzcnt=\listlen\zlist[1]\relax
       \ifnum\zcnt=\listlen\zlist[]\else\addcytoks{\\}\fi\else
         \addcytoks{#3_}\addcytoks[1]{\expandafter{\zzcnt}}%
       \addcytoks{&}\fi
     \fi
   }%
}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}%
\expandafter\tabbedCenterstack\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\endgroup
}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{\mysystem{orange!80!black}{cyan!80!black}{I}
  {6&-3&-1&&5\\-3&7&&-2&-23\\-1&&3&-1&5\\&-2&-1&4&3}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If different vertical space is desired between equations, one can alter this line in the preamble,

```
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
```

Comment: Very very good also this answer.

Comment: I think the OP didn't want +-2 ?

Comment: @Anush Thank you, I misunderstood it to the opposite.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes , thank you very much for your reply :O I've never used those packages before, except for `xcolor`, of course; so It's really nice to see an alternative method that doesn't rely on `systeme`. I liked it a lot :D Also, @Anush thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 4):

First, I guess from your code that you misunderstood the basic commands of the `xcolor` package. Its simplest commands that color a text are `\color` and `\textcolor`.

- `\textcolor` takes *two* mandatory arguments, the first being a valid color, and the second being the input you want to be output in that color. I think this is how you intended to use `\color`, but that's not how it works.
- `\color` takes only *one* mandatory argument which is a defined color. When you call `\color{R}`, you ask LaTeX to write everything (in the current group) that follows in the color `R`.

So for example when LaTeX reads `\color{R}{I_{1}}`, it switches to the color `R`, and then the reading continues from `{I_{1}}`, which is not taken as an argument of `\color`.

Also, I'm not totally sure how `\systeme` works, but as far as I know, it aligns the system of equations using the signs and the variables, so it seems probable to be that using color commands will mess up the alignment.

Hence, I think I would recommend you to use something else to make the system of equations. The following example uses an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{V}{HTML}{00a2e8}
\definecolor{R}{HTML}{fbc200}
\definecolor{B}{HTML}{000000}
\newcommand*{\I}[1]{\textcolor{B}{I_{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\p}{\textcolor{B}{+}}
\newenvironment{systemeq}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{>{\color{R}}r @{\mkern\medmuskip}%
                  >{\color{R}}c @{\mkern\medmuskip}%
                  >{\color{R}}r @{\mkern\medmuskip}%
                  >{\color{R}}c @{\mkern\medmuskip}%
                  >{\color{R}}r @{\mkern\medmuskip}%
                  >{\color{R}}c @{\mkern\medmuskip}%
                  >{\color{R}}r%
                  @{\mkern\thickmuskip{=}\mkern\thickmuskip}%
                  >{\color{V}}l}%
}{%
    \end{array}
    \right.
}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{systemeq}
     6\I{1} &  - & 3\I{2} &  - & 1\I{3} &    &        &   5 \\
    -3\I{1} & \p & 7\I{2} &    &        &  - & 2\I{4} & -23 \\
    -1\I{1} &    &        & \p & 3\I{3} &  - & 1\I{4} &   5 \\
            &  - & 2\I{2} &  - & 1\I{3} & \p & 4\I{4} &   3
\end{systemeq}
\]
\end{document}
```

This approach works well, but it is of course less automatic than the usual usage of the `\systeme` command.

Comment: Very good...I appreciate your answer....:-) It is done very well.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you very much. I thought there was no hope for formatting it using `systeme`, so I'm greatful you showed the way :) Also, thanks for clarifying how to use the command. I don´t know why exactly, but when I use `\color` in Texmaker, it just colors everything it finds in the same line, unless I use it to switch back to the original color. That doesn't happen on Overleaf, for example; but I couldn't use `systeme` there, so I needed an editor to which I could import that package. And that's the reason why I used `\color` so many times hehe